# Difference between pointer and reference in java

Tags: java, pointers, reference

Creating a reference in Java is same as the concept of pointer is exactly same, then why it is said that Java does not support pointers?

Comment: surely u could google this

Comment: PS: Found that duplicate by putting your exact question title into Google. Something you could've done yourself.

Answer (score -1):

In C you can manipulate pointers to get somewhere else than the pointer points to.  In Java references are atomic and only makes sense to get to an object in memory.